# How to use foreign-key attribute as error key instead of belongs_to association name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-api

I have two models: a `Post` and a `Comment`.

```rb
class Post
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment
  belongs_to :post
end
```

When I try to create a `Comment` without assigning a `Post`, I got the following validation errors as expected:

```rb
=> {
    :post => [
        [0] "can't be blank"
    ]
}
```

I'm writing a Rails API and I have a client-side form field named as `post_id`. When API validation returns, I need to manually map `post` errors to `post_id` errors to show them in my form.

Is there a way to map these `belongs_to` validation errors to the foreign-key attribute (`post_id`) instead of the association (`post`) for any `belongs_to` association in my Rails app?

All I wanted was this object as my error hash:

```rb
=> {
    :post_id => [
        [0] "can't be blank"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add you own validation on `post_id`:

```
validates :post_id, presence: true
```

This will generate an additional error keyed by `post_id`. The existing error comes from the automatically generated validation based on the association, and you probably shouldn't remove it. You can also, of course, filter / process the error hash however you like, but I'm guessing you're looking for a preferably Rails-only solution without additional logic to maintain.

Comment: One problem with this approach is that it won't let you create a post and comments at once. If you do `p = Post.new; p.comments.new; p.save` the save will fail since post_id is nil. Thats why the default validation checks if the association is set and not the fk attribute.

Comment: Admittedly its not a huge problem in this scenario but its something to bear in mind as it can cause issues when testing or seeding.

Comment: Good point. And yeah, but it's a pretty strong limitation to introduce just to have a little data formatting convenience. Probably better to just format the data.